# How to assign values of series to column names of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `Series` with values:

```
0               1_AA
1               2_BB
2               3_CC
3               4_DD
```

and I want to convert this series to names of dataframe columns. It should look like this:

```
       1_AA     2_BB     3_CC    4_DD
0
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could just use the `columns`-argument for `DataFrame`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> pd.DataFrame(columns=s)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

or pass it in directly as list:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(columns=['1_AA', '2_BB', '3_CC', '4_DD'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1_AA, 2_BB, 3_CC, 4_DD]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> s = pd.Series(['1_AA', '2_BB', '3_CC', '4_DD'])
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict.fromkeys(s, [0]))  # each column containing one zero - [0]
   1_AA  2_BB  3_CC  4_DD
0     0     0     0     0
```

Or [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which garantuees that the order of your values is always kept:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s, [0]))
   1_AA  2_BB  3_CC  4_DD
0     0     0     0     0
```

---

You could also use empty lists as second argument for `fromkeys`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict.fromkeys(s, []))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1_AA, 2_BB, 3_CC, 4_DD]
Index: []
```

But that creates an empty dataframe - with the *correct* columns.